# How to Ignore html comment tag in regex through python

Tags: python, html, regex, regexp-replace

I am replacing special character with some asci code and ignoring html tags with the help of below regex

`text_list = re.findall(r'>([\S\s]*?)<', html)`

So it is ignoring all html tags as we want it but is not ignoring html comment closing tag "-->".

Any help appreciated.
What should I changed in regex.

Attached screenshot for your reference.[image: here in second screen you could see acsi code replaced]

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions with HTML? Use an HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup.

Comment: We can not use soup because I am returning modification file.

Comment: You speak of "ignoring" and "replacing" but it doesn't fully explain what you're doing with your regex. You need to show more code or explain it better.

Comment: Who says you cannot modify a file using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Could you please give me example where I can replace special character with asci code with help of beautifulSoup . Would really helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try whil read the file please pass the multiple encoding parameters

Answer (score 1):

You may match them and discard using `re.findall`:

```py
text_list = list(filter(None, re.findall(r'(?s)<!--.*?-->|>(.*?)<', html)))
# Or, a bit more efficient:
text_list = list(filter(None, re.findall(r'<!--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->|>([^<]*)<', html)))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XdKLmK/1) (and the [second one](https://regex101.com/r/XdKLmK/2)).

The regex matches substrings between `<!--` and `-->` and matches substrings between `<` and `>`, *capturing* the text between the two latter delimiters into Group 1 and `re.findall` only returns the captures if there is a capturing group in the pattern.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hVQi1F):

```py
import re
html = "<a href='link.html'>URL</a>Some text <!-- Comment --><p>Par here</p>More text"
text_list = list(filter(None, re.findall(r'(?s)<!--.*?-->|>(.*?)<', html)))
print(text_list)
# => ['URL', 'Some text ', 'Par here']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried it but it is not working.. it is giving the same output.

Comment: @VishalJ That means you either have a different input  or you are not actually using my solution. Please use https://ideone.com/hVQi1F to show me what code and input *you* have if you need more help (click *fork*, edit the code, run and then share the new link with me).